# What are the recommended minimum payment options on an e-commerce site?

Tags: ecommerce, payments, customer-service

I've recently released a site that presently integrates with PayPal for taking payments, this doesn't require you to hold a PayPal account as you can submit credit cards through the PayPal checkout without having to sign-up etc.

But what other options would you say were recommended or perhaps even required to ensure you capture as many potential customers as possible?

EDIT: We accept payments worldwide by the way.

Comment: ,- Are you asking that we recommend the minimum payment for a product which we have not seen?

Comment: plimus, regnow, shareit, paypro, digital river - use google ;)

Comment: I think you are talking about ecommerce providers, I'm referring to payment types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take

- Fax orders by credit card (Yes people fax orders) both in the US and International
- Western Union, it's available in a lot of countries in Europe in their post offices
- Moneybookers, it's another form of PayPal popular in England
- SWIFT wire transfers
- Cash/Euros people will send cash if the price is right
- Cheque/Checks and International Money Orders

Answer (score 0):

Oh. I see. You want other payment method.

1. Direct deposit.
2. check deposit.
3. draft deposit
4. mobile payments.

Comment: I was asking more along the lines of Google Checkout, WorldPay, Merchant Account etc.